# Get PID of a specific application C#

Tags: c#, process, taskmanager

I try this:

```
int yourProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName( "notepad.exe" )[0].Id;
```

all i get is this error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

You tried to get processes by their **name**, but you didn't find any. That's your only error, you should specify a friendly name of the process. Or rather iterate through all processes and find the one you need.

Comment: Note this won't work on any internationalized Windows version, since friendly names will vary dependent of the language used.